# Makefile call from outside source

Tags: linux, makefile

I have project structure as:

project:

- src
- include
- obj
- bin
- Makefile

The makefile is as follows:

```
inc = -I include 
run : $(addprefix obj/,doubly-circular-linked-list.o node.o main.o)
      $(CXX) $^ -o bin/$@

obj/%.o : $(addprefix src/,$(patsubst %.o,%.c,doubly-circular-linked-list.o node.o main.o))
      $(CXX) $(inc) -c $< -o obj/$@

.PHONY : clean

clean : 
       rm -f obj/*.o bin/run
```

while making it gives the following error :

```
 *** No rule to make target 'obj/doubly-circular-linked-list.o', needed by 'run'.  Stop.
```

Please tell where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you have a line that starts with a tab that make can't find a target to which it belongs.

In this case I think your problem is a typo on the

```
 %.o = $(addprefix src/,$(patsubst %.o,%.c,doubly-circular-linked-list.o node.o main.o))
```

line. Specifically, you have `=` there instead of `:`.

That being said realize that that line will assign *every* `.c` file as a prerequisite of *every* `.o` file (i.e. that is not a one-to-one `.c` to `.o` file mapping).

Comment: I think your first sentence has a typo in it Etan... "a line that starts with a tab that make can't find a target to which it belongs" doesn't parse for me.  There's nothing about this question that's related to TAB problems.

Comment: @MadScientist There was before the edit. The error used to be "recipe commences before first target". And yes, that's an awkward sentence, I had trouble writing it succinctly.